# Scrollview not scrolling on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My scrollview doesnt scroll on android.

This is the XAML i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartTenancy.CustomRenderer;assembly=SmartTenancy"
             x:Class="SmartTenancy.ProfilePage">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <RelativeLayout x:name="firstnameField"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label x:Name="firstnameLabel" Text="FirstName:" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                        Property=Width,
                                        Factor=0}"/>
          <Entry x:Name="firstnameText" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                        Property=Width,
                                        Factor=0.5}"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout x:name="lastnameField"
          VerticalOptions="Start"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label x:Name="lastnameLabel" Text="LastName:" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                        Property=Width,
                                        Factor=0}"/>
          <Entry x:Name="lastnameText" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                        Property=Width,
                                        Factor=0.5}"/>
<-- The above RelativeLayout repeats another 15ish times --!>
        </RelativeLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have tried many diffrent variations of orientation, vertical options. On both the scrollview and the stackview.

After a great deal of searching i cant find out why this wont scroll. Vartiations of the above code seem to work fine for others.

I have only tested this on android.

Comment: I have a feeling it might be something with your VerticalOptions on your relative views. Trying leaving all your veritcal options to VerticalOptions="Start"

Comment: Don't use relative layout .. ever. Caveat when your SO score is over 1000 and your client forces you to then you may use relative layout.

Comment: What is a suitable substitute for relative layout? Also i have tried VerticalOptions="Start" with no luck unfortunately.